# UIWebView delegate and asynchronous loading

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to have a UIWebView size itself automatically based on its content and while this is easy enough to pull off the content it's being loaded is giving me some trouble

I have made a simple app to test this behavior, the code is as follows.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
{
    print(webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
    webViewHeight.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlstring, baseURL: nil)
    webView.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

htmlstring is as follows

```
<blockquote class=\"instagram-media\" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version=\"7\" style=\" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);\"><div style=\"padding:8px;\"> <div style=\" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50.0% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;\"> <div style=\"background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;\"></div></div> <p style=\" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;\"> <a href=https://www.instagram.com/p/BLpA4TKAdPr/ style= \" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;\" target=\"_blank\"></p></div></blockquote> <script async defer src=\"http://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js\"></script>
```

(it's an instagram embed)

Now the problem is if you try and run this webViewDidFinishLoad will be triggered multiple times, that's be expected of course but even after it's done its thing the resulting height is still incorrect as the embed will appear cut off

[image: the result]

I assume this is because the picture is loaded later via AJAX or something similar, which means at this point the height is not taking the picture (and possibly not even the caption?) into account

My question is with this particular type of content, which I cannot change, how can I tell when the process is truly over and get a correct size for the WebView?

Answer (score 0):

We watch the scrollview content size changes in Brave.app:

```
webView.scrollView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .New, context: nil)
```

and the receiver:

```
 override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "contentSize"  {
    // should give you correct height
        print(webview.scrollView?.contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Here is where this code sits in our app:
https://github.com/brave/browser-ios/blob/d9b5500de863625fc4e7f1ade8f6c428842f3063/brave/src/frontend/BraveScrollController.swift#L195

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it soon. Would this work with multiple UIWebViews? Unfortunately the client wants these embeds to be placed inside a table view with potentially hundreds of instances (it's awful, I know)

Comment: Yeah, we have multiple webviews in our app, not sure specifically where you forsee there might be a problem. 
Key path observation has facilities to indicate the sending object, such as:
`webView1.scrollView.addObserver(...); webView2.scrollView.addObserver(...)`

and in observeValueForKeyPath(..): `if object == webView1 { dosomething }`